# How do I check if a CPU's FPU is IEEE754 compliant?

Tags: python, c, virtual-machine, ieee-754, fpu

I want to be able to check if the FPU that I have or anyone has is IEEE754 compliant. How do I do it?

I tried using cpuinfo in python but the only thing I was able to get was that my CPU has an FPU.
I need this for a project so please any help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably can't, but the more important thing is whether your _language runtime_ is conformant for the types you care about (it might compensate in software for slight deviations in the hardware, for example).  That's why C++ has `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559`, for instance.

Comment: You didn't specify 32 or 64 bit compliance.  Or both.  (Technically, only one is required to claim compliance.)

Comment: For what it is worth, some hardware only achieves full compliance with software assistance; e.g. https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0274/h/programmer-s-model/compliance-with-the-ieee-754-standard/ieee-754-standard-implementation-choices

Comment: Of course ... the other way to find out is to read the documentation for your machine's chipset.

Comment: In summary, don't use floating point types where exactness is required.